# Access VBA code format updating table using form and subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently learning access and VBA at the moment . I am trying to update table in My access 2013 database using a form which also has a sub form embedded in to it. The table is called exam categories and has two fields both are text fields called ExamCatCode and ExamDescription. I have created a delete button on the form which would delete the record that is selected on the subform which displays the results of table. Previously I had ExamCatCode as a number format field and I was using the following code to delete the record:

CurrentDb.Execute "Delete from ExamCategories " & _
                " WHERE ExamCatCode=" & Me.ExamCategoriesSubform.Form.Recordset.Fields("ExamCatCode")

Now that I have changed the ExamCatCode to text format field the code is not working, I presume that I am missing a quote or an apostrophe somewhere, can some please set me straight. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM ExamCategories " & _
                  "WHERE ExamCatCode= '" & Me.ExamCategoriesSubform.Form![ExamCatCode] & "'", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, Thanks for your help. Do you know of any good sites that I can use a reference?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation on VBA here at stackoverflow. Besides that, anything nowdays can be found on google. Keep practicing and if you get stuck, we're here to help. :)